# stack thread proc/<pid>/maps

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm trying to see the stacks of various threads in C in proc//maps.
I've got a program in C that creates a couple of threads which sleep for some seconds and meanwhile I search in proc//maps, however I can only see one line maked as [stack] instead of 3 (one per thread) as I would expect.
Is there a way I can see the threads' stacks in proc//maps?

Comment: Were your threads created with `pthread_create`? Then there should be a few `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/maps` files, each with a different `[stack]` line. I don't know if threads created by giving other combinations of flags to  `clone` will have a correct `[stack]` line.